# How to override the .js file contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, stylesheet, datatables

i m using the datatable.js library in my application, but i need to modify certain styles in the datatable.js, its working fine if i directly modify the styles in .js file. Changes looks like below.

```
/* Sorting */
        "sSortAsc": "ui-state-default_custom",
        "sSortDesc": "ui-state-default_custom",
        "sSortable": "ui-state-default_custom",
        "sSortableAsc": "ui-state-default_custom",

/* Scrolling */
        "sScrollHead": "dataTables_scrollHead ui-state-default_custom",
        "sScrollFoot": "dataTables_scrollFoot ui-state-default_custom",
```

But this is not recommended as it makes changes directly to lib, is there a way to avoid and override these changes in some other file and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it exactly as it is described in the sourcecode :

> Extension object for DataTables that is used to provide all extension
>   options.
>
> Note that the DataTable.ext object is available through
>   jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext where it may be accessed and manipulated.

So, if you have a style like this

```css
.my-sorting {
    background-color: red;
}
```

and you want to use that class in sortable `<thead>`'s instead of the default `"sSortable": "sorting"` simply add this before your `dataTable()` initialization :

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.oStdClasses.sSortable='my-sorting';
```

You can change all of your above mentioned default properties by that, and much more, without changing the original source.

Here is a fiddle with the above example you can test on : http://jsfiddle.net/rbUAq/

Comment: Thanks Davidkonard, i tried the sample you have given me in the fiddle, If i add like that still old style only its considering. Suppose if i comment 'sSortAsc', 'sSortDesc' these in .js file then its considering the new style. I'm doing like this.    jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.oStdClasses.sSortAsc = 'ui-state-def1';
     jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.oStdClasses.sSortDesc = 'ui-state-def1';

      View.load("/Templates/mydatatavle.htm", function () {


                $("#Datatable").dataTable({

  "aoColumnDefs": [.....
});

Comment: I have updated with a new fiddle - see above. This _is_ the way to do it, at least the official recommended way. You can see in the updated fiddle that changing `sSortAsc` and `sSortDesc` (and so forth) actually is working. What doesnt work for you is probably due to some kind of MVC, where you - naturally - must add the changes to your view (or whatever it is), it seems you are loading, which - perhaps - holding the another reference to the datatables source. It is impossible for me to guess how your application flow is.

Comment: if i set "bJQueryUI": true, then your changes wont work, i tried now. keeping "bJQueryUI": true, i need these changes is it possible? can you help. I tried even you fiddle by updating "bJQueryUI": true. it wont change color at all.

Comment: Can you once try by setting "bJQueryUI": true, and run the fiddle, it wont consider changes at all.

Comment: Hey, at last problem is solved, if you sent "bJQueryUI": true, then instead of oStdClasses we need to use "oJUIClasses". Thanks for the help. But i have one more doubt, i.e i have this statement in .js file of datatable var nTd = document.createElement( 'td' ); and i have added one custom line i.e nTd.style.textAlign = "left"; how to prevent this and make in our js file, any idea.

Comment: Yes, when you set bjQueryUI it overrides the oSettings with oJUIClasses completely, so changes does not take effect. 2) I dont quite understand why you set textalign to left, is that not the default? Delete the line you have inserted? Does not really comprehrend.  I would never edit the datatables js file myself, so better make a plugin.

Comment: Yes thats true, i simply deleted that line, it worked well. So no code change is required. thanks for your help and quick reply for solving the issue. i will mark this ans as correct. Thank you verymuch once again for you :)